# Else If Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, cascading-dropdown

Hi there I am just looking to see if this is possible ?

I want to make a column such that if you choose a certain value from a choice column then it will give you another lot of values to choose from.

Example:

```
IF ([IncidentType] = "Fire")
{
  Choice ("False Alarm", "Evacuation", "Confirmed Event") ;
}
Else If ([IncidentType] = "Security")
{
  Choice ("Crime", "Alcohol Test", "Other")
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible using calculated column. This is something like cascading dropdown which you can achieve by customizing your list form.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible OOTB in SharePoint. You can either do it in PowerApps as shown [here](https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2018/03/cascading-dropdowns-in-powerapps-sharepoint-lookups/). or you can write JSLink on the form or simple javascript as shown [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/).